# cannot transfer packet via serial COM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, serial-port, linux-device-driver

I have a Linux Ubuntu installed on an Intel Panel PC. My code did not run so, I checked out packet transfer using cutecom. It does OPEN THE PORT successfully, but no data is transfered. I plugged the serial port to my own PC, it works. 
One thing crossed my mind that the error could have error come from was checking the BIOS, how ttyS0-3 are allocated. Bios shows S0 to 11 or upper. All in AVAILABLE mode, I set S3 to RESERVED and checked via cutecom again. NO TRANSFER!. 
On the other hand, I DO NOT THINK that a driver should be installed for distinguishing the PC COMs, it SHOULD identify them automatically.

```
/input0
[    0.416691] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]

[    0.416846] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input1

[    0.416859] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]

[    0.443708] serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A

[    0.557357] serial8250: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A

[    0.708888] serial8250: ttyS2 at I/O 0x3e8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A

[    0.872588] serial8250: ttyS3 at I/O 0x2e8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A

[    1.015669] 00:06: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A

[    1.036607] 00:07: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A

[    1.060599] 00:08: ttyS2 at I/O 0x3e8 (irq = 11) is a 16550A

[    1.084589] 00:09: ttyS3 at I/O 0x2e8 (irq = 10) is a 16550A

[    1.085551] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: detected gtt size: 262144K total, 262144K 

[   14.956323] serio: Serial port ttyS1

[   14.994250] serio: Serial port ttyS1

[   15.032073] input: Elo Serial TouchScreen as /devices/pnp0/00:07/tty/ttyS1/serio2/input
```

is there anything wrong with what dmesg shows? shall i change irqs using setirq?
if yes, please write me an example of the details please.

Comment: Try asking here: http://askubuntu.com/. Since this is not a programming question, I don't think it will be answered at SO.

Comment: Which device do you have connected. What baud rate, data bits, stop bits, parity were used? What is the initial command you sent to get data back?